# how to update the value of select tag using javascript and these values can be multiple vaues

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, foreach

```js
    var expanded = false;

    function showCheckboxes() {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
        if (!expanded) {
            checkboxes.style.display = "block";
            expanded = true;
        } else {
            checkboxes.style.display = "none";
            expanded = false;
        }
    }
```

```css
.selectBox {
        position: relative;
    }

        .selectBox select {
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    .overSelect {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    #checkboxes {
        display: none;
        border: 1px #dadada solid;
    }

        #checkboxes label {
            display: block;
        }

            #checkboxes label:hover {
                background-color: #1e90ff;
            }
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Department</label>
  <div>
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select  class="form-control">
        <option>-Select a Department-</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" />bscs<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" />bsit<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" />mscs<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" />msit<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" />bba<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" />Dpt<br>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I am using checkbox in drop down list and  is filled by dynamic values and i want to get checked values from the list and submit these values in the form.

**Controller's Action method code**

```
FYP_DB_Entities obj = new FYP_DB_Entities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.dept = obj.Departments.ToList();

        return View();
    }
```

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
    <select class="form-control">
                                    <option>-Select a Department-</option>
                                </select>
    <div class="overSelect"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="checkboxes">
    @foreach (var s in ViewBag.dept) {
      <label for="@s.Department_Id"><input type="checkbox" id="@s.Department_Id" />@s.Department_Id</label> 
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot of the dropdownlist before Clicking on it

[image]

After Clicking on it

[image]

Comment: Use the `<>` snippet editor to create a [mcve] with HTML and JS instead of templates

Comment: If you wrap them in a form they will be submitted

Comment: @mplungjan  it is already wrapped in <form> tag

Comment: So what seems to be the issue? Errors in console? Server errors?

Comment: @mplungjan now i have added the code snippet

Comment: @mplungjan the issue is that whatever i select, the value of drop down list remains the same which is "-Select a Department-" but i want to update this with the checked values

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and tricky way to do this is to keep checkboxes code inside the Form tag and use the **same name** for all the checkboxes with **different ids** (to make them work for "for" attribute of label tag). Also, set the value of checkbox to departmentId. Your code will look like this:

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    @foreach (var s in ViewBag.dept) {
      <label for="@s.Department_Id"><input type="checkbox" id="@s.Department_Id" name="selectedDepartmentIds" value="@s.Department_Id" />@s.Department_Id</label> 
    }
  </div>
```

add a new parameter at controller's action with name **selectedDepartmentIds** of type array. When you submit the form you will get selected department ids.